# How to rollback to previous state if any failure happened while parallelly loading data into Snowflake

Tags: datatable, parallel-processing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, restore, rollback

While loading data into Snowflake tables parallelly, How can I rollback to previous states in tables if any failure happened.

[image: Data loading parallelly]

This is the scenario:

1. I have loaded data into staging layer and now I want to move data into modeling layer
2. There are several batches run sequentially and in each batch there are tables load parallelly.
3. If one batch passed successfully, it will continue with next batch execution (Ex : Batch 1 to Batch 2)
4. Assume that, in batch 2 "Table 7" loading failed due to data type issues or something.
5. Now the batch 3 execution will be stopped and entire operation will be halted.

How can I restore to the previous states in tables in batch 2 (Table 5,6) and batch 1 (Table 1,2,3,4). Means I want to rollback the entire execution and successfully loaded tables should not have the new changes(Inserts/Updates).

Programmatic Time travel procedure? or any mechanism. Hope your suggestions here.

Comment: In case of failures , snowflake sets a load status in the table metadata for the data files referenced in the copy command. When batches are re-triggered it will ignore loaded tables and starts from point of failure. Snowflake tags those files as failures.

Other options would be restre the tables using timetravel option.

Comment: Are you saying that the data is loaded into Snowflake already and these batches are going from staging -> modelled layer? If so, why would you need to do this in batches rather than running a big insert statement in a single transaction?

Comment: @Simon D There are around 20-30 big table in the modeling layer and we are planning to ingest data from staging table to modeling tables with Airflow. So we are following a batch execution to load them parallelly. If its a single transaction, It will take more time I guess

Comment: hmm, I think you'd have to manage this yourself with some sort of ETL metadata table. You could manage this in airflow too, if all tasks are in a single DAG then you can detect failures in Airflow and delete the data that has already been loaded.